# AWS: Using id token and access token generated by cognito in lambda functions

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito, serverless, aws-serverless

I am looking for solution on how to make use of id token and access token generated by AWS Cognito after login. I followed the tutorial:[link](https://medium.com/@Da_vidgf/using-cognito-for-users-management-in-your-serverless-application-1695fec9e225) to implement amazon cognito with serverless. I am able to generate id_token & access_token. I am not sure how to make use of these tokens in lambda functions while executing. Should I add headers with certain details to make my lambda function work.

Everytime I get below error while executing API

```
{
    "message": "Unauthorized"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please add `Authorization id_token` to header and perform API call. Make sure you have configured cognito authorizer at API gateway.

Please feel free to share your output then